# Symfony form inline radios with text fields

Tags: php, twig, symfony-forms, symfony

In Symfony I have a twig page that displays a form with text fields and check boxes. The form contains data for a question and four possible answers. The user can edit the data and select one answer that is correct.
At the moment I have all the text fields where the user can change the data and four check boxes. Instead of the check boxes I need radio buttons(this is to allow the user to select only one choice). Also I need the check boxes to be on the right hand side of text fields for each possible answer. How can I do this in Symfony. Would much appreciate some help.Thanks.

Using Collection of Forms to build the entire Form

**Answer Form:**

```
class AnswerFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('answer');
        $builder ->add('isCorrect', null , array('label' => false,));
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'QuizBundle\Entity\Answer'));
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'quiz_bundle_answer_form_type';
    }
}
```

**Question Form:**

```
class QuestionFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('image');
        $builder->add('question');
        $builder->add('answers', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => AnswerFormType::class));
        $builder->add('Submit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Submit'));
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'QuizBundle\Entity\Question'));
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'quiz_bundle_question_form_type';
    }
}
```

**This is my Twig:**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    Edit record page

    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.image) }}
    {{ form_row(form.question) }}

    {% for answers in form.answers %}
        <li>{{ form_row(answers.answer) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}

    {{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Comment: @Alsatian  yes i need text fields because the user needs to be able to edit the answers. And i need radio buttons because the user needs to select which of the edited answers is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

You can not mix a radio input with text inputs to let the user edit them.

It is not possible with HTML.

No other choice, you have to :

- Recreate the radio behavior with Javascript on the client side
- Write some CSS to make your checkboxes looks like radio boxes.
- Attach a form constraint which validates only one checkbox is selected after submit.

To put the text inputs at the right side, you have to customize the form widgets. Take a look at the documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to do because of your previous question. For layout of the form, you can do something like this to make it look better:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

{{ form_label(form.image) }}{{ form_widget(form.image) }}
{{ form_label(form.question) }}{{ form_widget(form.question) }}

{% for ans in form.answers %}
<li>{{ form_label(ans.answer) }}{{ form_widget(ans.answer) }}
        {{ form_label(ans.isCorrect) }}{{ form_widget(ans.isCorrect) </li>

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

However, I don't think this is the solution for you. Like Alsatian mentioned, you need to use Javascript to check for "onchange" events for the radio buttons. You are creating a form class, which in my opinion doesn't always work for every design. You might try just a "createFormBuilder" instead and customize exactly as you need.

```
public function showQuestionFormAction($ansID, Request $request){

// Get Answers...
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$qb->select('a')
    ->from('AppBundle:Answer', 'a')
    ->where('a.answer_id = :ansID')
    ->setParameter('ansID', $ansID);
$ans = $qb->getQuery()->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();

$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('image')      // Not sure what type this is???
    ->add('question', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Question',
            'label' => 'Question:',
            'choice_label' => 'question',   // Label shown.
            'choice_value' => 'question_id',    // What data you want returned.
            'attr' => array('class' => 'question_id'),  // For css styling only, you may not need this.
            'data' => $ques->getText(), // This is a method (getter) to get question text.
    ))
    ->add('ans1', RadioType::class, array(
            'label' => '$ans->getAnswer1()',
            'required' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                    'onchange' => "check_answer('ans1')",   // Javascript function.
                    'checked' => true,
            ),
    ))
    ->add('ans2', RadioType::class, array(
        'label' => '$ans->getAnswer2()',
        'required' => false,
        'attr' => array(
                'onchange' => "check_answer('ans2')",   // Javascript function.
                'checked' => false,
        ),
    ))
    ...
```

Then you can use a simple javascript function like so. I made this quickly, so there may be a better/simpler way to design this.

```
// script/check_answer.js

function check_answer(id){
    var ans1 = document.getElementById("form_ans1");
    var ans2 = document.getElementById("form_ans2");
    var ans3 = document.getElementById("form_ans3");
    var ans4 = document.getElementById("form_ans4");

    // Check what is changed.
    if(id == 'ans1'){
        ans2.checked = false;
        ans3.checked = false;
        ans4.checked = false;
    }
    if(id == 'ans2'){
        ans1.checked = false;
        ans3.checked = false;
        ans4.checked = false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps.